# Conflict between docker-proxy and nginx

Tags: docker, nginx, https, docker-proxy

I want to run a dockerized `nginx` on port 443 (https), but this seems to be taken by the `docker-proxy`.

Why is this, and can I do someting about it?

### EDIT

The same conflict happens with the `http` port (80)

Comment: what error are you getting? are you using Ubuntu as a host machine? please check port 80 and 443 whats running over there?

Answer (score 0):

`docker-proxy` is run when you publish a port on the host. Look for the container or service you have run that is publishing the port and remove it:

```
$ docker container ls
$ docker service ls
```